# Excel import process in Asp.Net Mvc appears with the progress bar as much as the number of data in excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I want it to appear with the progress bar when the excel import process is completed in Asp.Net Mvc. The number of data I want in excel, the progress bar should progress as much as the number of data in excel. How can I do that? I have to solve it very quickly. Please can you help me?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
    {

        var mapList = new List<AWSServerless_Google_Geocoding_Mvc.Models.Map>();
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 1; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var map = new AWSServerless_Google_Geocoding_Mvc.Models.Map();

                        map.UserID = null;
                        map.Name = null;
                        map.Latitude = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();
                        map.Longitude = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString();
                        map.Address = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value.ToString();

                        mapList.Add(map);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        using (LocationDBEntities db = new LocationDBEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in mapList)
            {
                db.Map.Add(item);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

This is a snippet of my javascript code:

```
var bar = $('.progress-bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');
var files = $("#FileUpload").get(0).files;

$('#Myform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#status').empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        $('.progress-bar').width(percentVal);
        $('.percent').html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            $('.progress-bar').width(percentVal);
            $('.percent').html(percentVal);
        }
    },
    complete: function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.success == true) {
            setTimeout(function () {// wait for 5 secs(2)
                swal({
                    title: "Başarılı!",
                    text: "Kayıt Başarılı!",
                    type: "success",
                    showCancelButtonClass: "btn-primary",
                    confirmButtonText: "OK"
                });
                location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
});
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a progress indicator for the server side processing of the uploaded file then the right and easiest way to do this is with SignalR that allows you to send live data from server to client , you may find a detailed tutorial that teaches the basics of building a real-time app using SignalR in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio and you may find a simple project that shows how to use SignalR in ASP.NET MVC application to track progress of some long running process and display on client side using Bootstrap modal in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D